# How to extract a column from a nxnxn array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, extract

I have a 40 x 40 x 40 array in Python and would like to extract all i values with k=10 index. I understand how to do this with a nxn array but not a nxnxn array.
Thanks

Comment: how do you extract it for `NxN` array?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Numpy Index documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/how-to-index.html?highlight=boolean%20indexing).

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(3*4*5).reshape( 3,4,5 )
arr
#  array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#          [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#          [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#          [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

#         [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
#          [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
#          [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
#          [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

#         [[40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
#          [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
#          [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
#          [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]])

arr[:,:,1]  # For k = 1 
# or arr[ ...,1] as its the last index
```

This returns a 2d array.

```
array([[ 1,  6, 11, 16],
       [21, 26, 31, 36],
       [41, 46, 51, 56]])
```